# Can I use one voltage divider for multiple voltage comparators?

Tags: adc, comparator

I have a circuit that uses multiple comparators, that are comparing the same threshold.

Could I use just one voltage divider for all of the comparators, or if I need a sperate voltage divider for each comparator? If it helps, I am using a lm339 (quad comparator).

Here is a simplified diagram of what i am asking:

[image: simplified circuit example]

Comment: Welcome! On top of what Andy said below, take a look in the datasheet for your comparator under input impedance. Calculate how much that impedance in parallel with the bottom R in your voltage divider will affect your circuit. Repeat for several. Still within your specification?

Comment: @winny the data sheet doesn't specify input impedance (probably because the input bias current is dominant and always flows out of the input pins due the the PNP nature of the input stage).

Comment: @Andyaka Good point! Zackery - Calculate the impact of the _current sink_ en parallel with your lower resistor how much influence it will have. It will hopefully build your understanding for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use one voltage divider for multiple voltage comparators?

Yes. With caveats - the first of which would be that LM339 without hysteresis is not the best idea, at least not at first.

You'll want positive feedback for hysteresis. That's how you'd want to start, and then only remove the feedback if prototype testing proves it unnecessary *and* you're really trying to shave cents off the final cost. If the production volume isn't in the tens of thousands (or more) - it's not worth it. Just always put the hysteresis in.

In most LM339 "hobby" applications, some degree of hysteresis is required to get repeatable, oscillation-free response in spite of varying input slew rate. It also works around the deficiencies of ground-plane-less construction, such as on a 2-layer protoboard.

**Caution**: In the schematics below, the "1/4 LM339" box is a model of the behavior of one comparator in the LM339 package. That entire "box" represents one comparator symbol on your schematic. *Do not be fooled by the input polarity of the CMP10 internal building block* - it's opposite to the indicated polarity of the LM339 it models!

To prevent multiple comparators from interfering with each other, the reference voltage has to be buffered. The buffer output has low impedance and can drive multiple comparator blocks.

For best performance when buffering fixed DC voltages, the LM358 op-amp requires about 1mA pull-down current to ground: the REF voltage has to be loaded to ground by R9=REF*1kΩ/V. In this fashion, LM358 can reliably buffer voltages down to about +0.5V, and its transient load response is also improved as the output stage operates in Class A.

LM358 is a good match for LM339, since the output voltage range of LM358 and the input voltage range of LM339 are similar. **This circuit works with REF in the range of +0.5V to (VCC-3V).** For reference voltages within 3V of the positive supply voltage (here: above +9V), a different comparator and buffer have to be used, or the circuit has to be otherwise modified.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcofGq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- R1/(R1+R2) sets the reference voltage - here at 4.0V
- R3,C2 isolate the transient reference loading from OA1's output
- R4/R5 ratio establishes the size of the hysteresis
- R8 sets the output impedance
- R6+R7 set the output high state voltage - here 3.3V
- R6/R7 ratio controls the hysteresis symmetry, so that the reference on the (+) input to LM339 swings approximately symmetrically around REF voltage as the output state changes

Multiple comparator blocks can be attached to the REF voltage by replicating the contents of the "ONE COMPARATOR CHANNEL" box.

Design process:

1. Choose R1,R2 for desired reference voltage
2. Choose R8 for output impedance - shouldn't be too high or the output risetime will be much longer than the fall time.
3. Choose R6+R7 for the desired high output logic level when LM339 is disconnected.
4. Adjust the ratio R6/R7, while keeping their sum fixed, so that in either output logic state, the hysteresis around the reference voltage, as shown by VM1, has the same magnitude. Here it's about +/-10mV.

The input, reference and output voltages are shown below.

[image: The waveform of the input voltage V1, 4V reference voltage REF, and the output voltage OUT1.]

The hysteresis action can be seen on the positive input to LM339:

[image: Vertically magnified waveform of the input voltage V1, reference voltage REF, and the positive terminal voltage on the LM339]

If the reference voltage has to be lower than the logic output HIGH level + about 0.7V, the hysteresis- and output pickup nodes have to be exchanged.

For example, for +1.0V reference voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8qfyv.png)</sup>

Design process:

1. Choose R1,R2 for desired reference voltage.
2. Choose R7+R8 for output impedance (1k-5k typically).
3. Choose R6 for desired output HIGH level when LM339 is disconnected.
4. Adjust the ratio R7/R8 while keeping their sum fixed, to obtain symmetric hysteresis offset (measured on VM1) around the REF voltage for both HIGH and LOW output states.

[image: The waveform of the input voltage V1, 1V reference voltage REF, and the output voltage OUT1.]

Comment: I have a small question about your circuit diagram, what does R9 do (the resistor that is placed in between Vref and ground)?

Comment: @ZackeryFleming It makes the LM358's output stage run in class A instead of class B, by pulling 1mA output current at all times. This improves the buffered REF stability in face of transients through the hysteresis load resistors. It also allows LM358's output voltage to go quite close to the ground - which it wouldn't do without such a load. Since the reference voltage is fixed, a fixed resistor does a good job at pulling a fixed current - otherwise you'd need a current source. But that's explained in paragraph 6 that begins with "For best performance when [...]"

Answer (score 8):

> *My question is if I could use just one voltage divider for all of the
> comparators, or if I need a sperate voltage divider for each
> comparator?*

Providing you are not using positive feedback on the reference node, a single resistor divider can be used multiple times. There will be some degradation due to input bias currents for each added comparator but, if you set the two resistors at a "low-enough" value, this can be largely avoided.

You can also buffer the two resistor dividers with a unity gain op-amp to improve things. Don't forget that the LM339 needs pull-up resistors on the output.

Comment: Would a 10k pullup resistor be fine? Also, the datasheet has a capacitor placed on the output to ground, what is his for?

Comment: @ZackeryFleming higher switching speed comes with lower value pull-up resistors so, it depends but, 10k is a rough broad value that might be used (many times I've seen 1k and 10k). Please link the data sheet you are using and explain which circuit diagram you refer to.

Comment: datasheet on pg. 23: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339b.pdf?ts=1676963620598&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.co.uk%252F

Comment: @ZackeryFleming if you look throughout the data sheet, the standard circuit they specify for a lot of the tables and graphs assume a load capacitance of 15 pF is fitted. Clearly it will be quicker (a tad) without it but, that's their way of making the tests and specs more realistic to a typical "real" circuit. Ignore what hoagie said above; I don't have a clue what he's driving at.

Comment: @ZackeryFleming if we are done here you should take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Of course, if you still have queries on this then ask.